# UWP BackgroundTransfer StartAsync but don't wait for task to complete

Tags: .net, uwp, background-task, background-transfer

Is it possible to start DownloadOperation but not to wait for the download to complete? Basically, I want to write a background task that runs on Timer, schedules some number of downloads and finishes. Code that handles progress/complete is planned to run separately via AttachAsync when the user awakes UI to monitor the progress.

I mean I need something like an old-school approach that calls "void/Task RunDownload" but is not obliged to subscribe to events like OnProgress/OnCompleted.

Calling

`downloader.CreateDownload(uri, file).StartAsync()`

without await is a bad idea - I want to be sure the operation is scheduled and later accessible via BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()

Comment: You could make  void method to package the  native downloader.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT What do you mean? Can you show an example of a wrapper for the code above, please?

Comment: Sure, I will post sample code below.